# How to customize the default self sign up page in wso2is

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I want to add some customization like a picker field and checkbox in the default sign-up form given by wso2is.

EXAMPLE: I have a list of organizations and when user signup he/she selects related organization from a list and the organization gets stored in the DB.

one more example can be: I can provide list of Countries and users will be able to select respective countries.

Comment: What is the organization here you are referring to? Are they external IDPs?

Comment: it is just a list from which user can pick one option so that i know where user work.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this information or the value from the dropdown? Do you want to store it as a user claim/attribute?

Comment: yes, i want to store this with other user properties from where i can use it later.

Answer (score 0):

Attributes that you can see in the default self sign up page are the claims that have been configured as `Supported by Default` in the WSO2 claim dialect (`http://wso2.org/claims`).

So if the required attributes are already not there in the default self sign up page you can configure them as `Supported by Default` from the management console. Please refer the [documentation](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/self-registration-and-account-confirmation/) for more details.

After that, if you want to have a drop-down for some attributes you have to customize the self sign up page. The relevant JSP page (`self-registration-with-verification.jsp`) can be found in the `accountrecoveryendpoint` web app which can be located at `<IS-HOME>/repository/deployment/server/webapps` folder. So you can do the customization there as for your requirement.

Also if you want to build a separate Self Sign-Up page using a preferable technology you can use the [Self Sign-Up REST APIs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS590/apidocs/self-registration/) as well.

Comment: I have made changes to self-registration-with-verification.jsp, but the changes dose not reflects when i restart the server.

Comment: Could you please mention the IS version that you are currently working on?

Comment: the version of my WSO2IS is 5.10.0